# Google Sheets - Email Specific Range With Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LSI_fIidbbK9WTSqAnFLYUYpybuxRhBigKY7_l5-6cw/edit?usp=sharing

I want A1:E9 emailed out when I hit the button. It sounds simple!

I can just copy and paste that range into gmail, and it looks exactly how I want. However I am guessing scripts won't retain the formatting? Do any of you have an idea on how to do this?

I guess I need HTML? But how would I create a script to do this?

For excel, I get it to take a screenshot and attach it to an email. However I am hoping there is a much easier way for google sheets.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

Follow this guide!
[Emailing Google Sheet range (with or without formatting) as a HTML table in a Gmail message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529890/emailing-google-sheet-range-with-or-without-formatting-as-a-html-table-in-a-gm)

Worked - almost too perfectly.