# Cc and Bcc not working, I'm getting back the error "Invalid email: [L<?>;@34c5bdeb"

Tags: email, google-apps-script, cc, bcc, macos-mail-app

I was following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529890/emailing-google-sheet-range-with-or-without-formatting-as-a-html-table-in-a-gm) to create an image from a spreadsheet keeping the same color and format to be sent as an email.

Now while I try to send the email as "cc" or "bcc", I get back an error that says "Invalid email: [L;@34c5bdeb (line 34, file "Send Email")". All the emails that I'm using are working, comma-separated and without any symbol. If I use the same emails as "To" they work great; I don't know what the error could be.

```
  var image = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);

  var HTML = "Team," + 
      "<br/><br/>Below you will find the summary for the Overview of the Billing files." +
      "<br/><br/>" + msg +
      "<br/><br/>" + image +
      "<br/><br/>Best regards,";
  return HTML;
}

function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ALERTS');
  var EmailSettings = ss.getRange('E5:E9').getValues(); // getting information for the email to be sent
  var EmTo = EmailSettings[0];
  var emailcc = EmailSettings[1];
  var emailbcc = EmailSettings[2];
  var EmSubject = EmailSettings[3];
  var EmMessage = EmailSettings[4];
  var dataRange = ss.getRange('A1:B22'); //Range to be converted into an image

  var HTML = convSheetAndEmail(dataRange, EmMessage);
  var options = {
    name: "TEST EMAIL GROUP",
    htmlBody: HTML,
    cc:emailcc,
    bcc:emailbcc
  };

  Email(EmTo, EmSubject, options);
}

function Email(email, subject, options) {
 MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, '', options);
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `[0]`:`var emailcc = EmailSettings[1][0];`

Comment: It worked! I really appreciate your help!